# how to set a cookie from an offline application

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Is there any way to set cookies from an offline application running javascript (acrojs or similar) to retreive from borwser later?

Comment: Have you tried the normal way (like you would do in an online application)? What did it say/why didn't that work?

Comment: Tried in AcroJS but it does not recognise "document" keyword.

Comment: No. Cookies are bound to domain names they are set from, meaning you can't set cookies from a local application and access them from a different domain in the browser.

Comment: Of course! I feel so stupid right now @Karaman